# Документация по Android на русском

Tags: android

Где можно найти подробную информацию, как в [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com), только на русском?

Comment: Никакой справочник и учебник не может заменить по полноте официального руководства. Так что, как это ни печально, надо учить английский.

Comment: Английский заметно лучше. После того, как я начал читать на русском книгу по андроиду и увидел "явления", "намерения" и "видения".... я понял, что больше не протяну читать:) и перешел назад на английский вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Недавно вот наткнулся на ресурс [Android. Переводы References](http://surr6.blogspot.ru/?view=flipcard). Переведено мало, качество посредственное, но, может, кому-то и поможет.

Answer (score 1):

На русском нет! Более менее можно посмотреть в книге Голощапов А.Л. Голощапов - Google Android. Программирование для мобильных устройств.

Comment: А больше ничего не посоветуете?

Comment: Просто эту книгу я уже читал

Comment: пожалуй лучшая книга по Android - http://nnm-club.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=423541